# JavaScript Prepended Content Not Showing On Anchor Click In Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari, onclick

I'm working on a project in WordPress that is utilizing the Theme Customizer to assist other people working on the site with me. We're dynamically loading in a lot of content and options like Google Fonts, so the loading of the Customizer takes a few seconds to fully load (lingers on the admin page, then after a few seconds progresses to the /customize.php page).

Because of this, I wanted to add a simple "Customizer Loading" message that would pop up to let users know that something was happening. Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari and Internet Explorer (as far as I can tell from testing in Sauce) are giving me problems.

I'm using the following bit of JavaScript to add the loading message:

```js
$('a[href="customize.php"]').click( function() {
  $('head').prepend('<style type="text/css"></style>');
  $('body').prepend('<div id="loading-message"></div>');
});
```

Inside the `<style type="text/css">` block I simply included my styles and then `<div class="loading-message"></div>` is where I placed my content.

What is happening in Safari (and again, IE from what I can tell) is that when `<a href="customize.php">...</a>` is clicked, the styles and content are getting added to the DOM (I can see them when I inspect the page), but they don't actually become visible, whereas in Chrome and Firefox they do.

If I use `e.preventDefault()` on the link, the loading message shows up just fine. Other events, like `alert()` and `console.log()` register fine, and the link will continue on through as expected. It's only the new content getting added to the DOM that doesn't become visible.

I can't figure out exactly what could be causing this and would greatly appreciate any help. I tried recreating the problem in JSFiddle, but I couldn't replicate the same result I'm getting in the WordPress Admin Panel (if you change out `$('a[href="customize.php"]')` for any other slug in the backend like "themes.php", it has the same result though).

Comment: Is it working if your styles are initially part of an existing loaded stylesheet?

Comment: I've tried that as well, that also doesn't work. It's like in Safari once an anchor click is registered, no changes to the page are displayed. What else is odd as well is that if I hit back after going through to the Customizer, the loading message will be displayed and I have to refresh for it to go away.

Comment: Have you tried using `e.preventDefault()` perform the changes and then  follow the link `location.href = 'clicked link';`. You can always try to follow the link only after a certain delay using `setTimeout` as well, just to see what it gives.

Comment: It's redirecting the page it seems but it's preventing the prepended content from displaying, haha. It's like I can only have one or the other.

Comment: Well that's almost impossible if you are using the `setTimeout` approach to delay the redirection process. Have you tried this way?

Comment: plalx, maybe I had a syntax error. How would you write it out given the example in my original post?